# Purpose of holding a strong local copy of a delegate variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, delegates

As part of [ResearchKit](https://github.com/ResearchKit/), I have seen code like this:

```
- (void)finishWithReason:(ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason)reason error:(NSError *)error {
    __strong typeof(self.delegate) strongDelegate = self.delegate;
    if ([strongDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(taskViewController:didFinishWithReason:error:)]) {
        [strongDelegate taskViewController:self didFinishWithReason:reason error:error];
    }
}
```

What's the purpose of storing a *local strong variable* pointing to the delegate before calling its method? Is this to prevent the delegate being freed from another thread between the `respondsToSelector:` check and the method call? Can this happen at all?

If that's the case, why would you want to call the delegate method? Why not let it be freed and perform the no-op that is sending a message to a *nil* pointer variable?

Comment: I think possibly if the delegate is freed before calling respondsToSelector, the respondsToSelector call would cause exception (EXC_BAD_ACCESS?). Since this method only applicable to NSObject. But if this is the case, I think a strongDelegate != nil checking still need to be done before calling the respondsToSelector method.

Comment: Would be eager to learn otherwise, but I think it's total nonsense.  The .delegate is either already freed or not, and either nil or not when this method runs.  It cannot be freed while this method runs.  And no incantation at the start, copying the pointer to a stack variable (which is strong by default anyway) changes those conditions.

Comment: @zp_x: I'm afraid you are wrong, weak variables are nilled when they are deallocated, and sending messages to `nil` variables is just a no-op.

Comment: @danh: It seems we were both wrong! See the very informative answer by Daniel Hall. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Clang warnings that flag messages sent to weak (possibly nil) pointers, and repeatedly accessing weak (possibly nil) pointers. These encourage the developer to reason about "what if this pointer *is* nil when I'm accessing it?" and "what if this weak reference goes nil *after* I test for not nil?" and requires temporary strong storage in the calling scope to satisfy the compiler.

Regarding your specific question about whether it's possible for a delegate (or other weakly referenced object) to be freed from another thread in between testing the "if" condition and the next line of code, the answer is yes, as noted in the description accompanying the warning being added to LLVM here:

http://reviews.llvm.org/rL164854

As to the question about why not let the delegate be freed and just have the message be a no op to a nil pointer: the compiler has no way of understanding whether that behavior is safe or intended, and so requires the developer (if you have those warnings enabled) to use a strong reference to the receiving object as a guarantee that the message will succeed as the code implies it is expected to.

More discussion on this in the WWDC 2013 "Advances in Objective-C" session here:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/404/  (around 47:30)

And in the mailing list thread here:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2012/Aug/msg00001.html